# Ember CLI - Babel is too slow on Mac

Tags: ember-cli, babeljs

From last couple of days my ember is slow, here is the output

```
version: 2.4.2
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/

Build successful - 76337ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel                                         | 70809ms             

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (20)                                    | 72361ms (3618 ms)
```

How can I debug and fix it. I have checked it on Mac(SSD + 16gb Ram)

### Edit

After updating npm to latest version, cleaning npm cache, and reinstalling all node packages. It was quite fast but after couple of rebuilds, it became slow again.

```
Build successful - 56809ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel                                         | 55422ms             

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (20)                                    | 55580ms (2779 ms)
```

### Edit #2

Is there anything to do with which file it changed here are two results

```
file changed site/components/site/carpets/neworderform-form/template.hbs - 1822 lines in this template

Build successful - 62844ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel                                         | 61122ms             

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (20)                                    | 61280ms (3064 ms)   

file changed site/components/site/countries/country-form/template.hbs - 64 lines total in this template

Build successful - 1322ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
SourceMapConcat: Concat: App                  | 424ms               
SourceMapConcat: Concat: App Tests            | 77ms                

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
SourceMapConcat: Concat: App (1)              | 424ms               
Babel (20)                                    | 199ms (9 ms)        
SourceMapConcat: Concat: App Tests (1)        | 77ms
```

## Edit 3 (after 2 days)

Now I guess I really should fix this or else I cant work on it.

```
Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel                                         | 146179ms            

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (20)                                    | 170889ms (8544 ms)
```

Comment: which version of babel?

Comment: I guess its `5.8.38` in my package.json it is `"ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5",`

Comment: check node_modules/ember-cli-babel/package.json

Comment: Its `ember-cli-babel@5.1.6` i used `npm list ember-cli-babel` in project folder to get this

Comment: please be sure to read the performance guide: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/PERF_GUIDE.md  which provides thoughts/ideas to improve performance as well as clearer instructions on how to report actionable issues.